# Dataframe from multiple json files in R or Python

Tags: python, json, r

I have a mydata.txt/.json file containing data like this:

```
[{"num":1,"name":"Swab Summer: Transformation At the United States Coast Guard Academy","link":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/dp\/0982168594\/ref=wl_it_dp_v_nS_ttl\/176-1400914-4673658?_encoding=UTF8&colid=1GM97SGAP8NLI&coliid=I1ELS7DSQ6QV5C","old-price":"N\/A","new-price":"","date-added":"January 10, 2014","priority":"","rating":"N\/A","total-ratings":"","comment":"","picture":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51MtOOm493L._SL500_SL135_.jpg","page":1}]
[{"num":1,"name":"Vibomex","link":"http:\/\/www.amazon.com\/dp\/B00BR1CUFY\/ref=wl_it_dp_v_S_ttl\/175-5687209-2417046?_encoding=UTF8&colid=C0XVZ38E5WD9&coliid=I1EPDGRY73N5Q2","old-price":"N\/A","new-price":"","date-added":"July 20, 2014","priority":"","rating":"N\/A","total-ratings":"","comment":"","picture":"http:\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/31GBqOHskyL._SL500_SL135_.jpg","page":1}]
```

Basically, multiple json files. These are two separate rows. Now, when I'm trying to import the data in R and making it a dataframe, its only reading the lines corresponding to the first row. Below is my code:

```
library(rjson)
json_file <- fromJSON(file="mydata.txt")
json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})
do.call("rbind", json_file)
```

Can anybody help me with reading lines corresponding to each row of mydata.txt/json in a single dataframe in R or python. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, using the `fromJSON` offered in the `jsonlite` package:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(readLines('mydata.json'), jsonlite::fromJSON))

#   num                                                                 name                                                                                                                                   link
# 1   1 Swab Summer: Transformation At the United States Coast Guard Academy http://www.amazon.com/dp/0982168594/ref=wl_it_dp_v_nS_ttl/176-1400914-4673658?_encoding=UTF8&colid=1GM97SGAP8NLI&coliid=I1ELS7DSQ6QV5C
# 2   1                                                              Vibomex   http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00BR1CUFY/ref=wl_it_dp_v_S_ttl/175-5687209-2417046?_encoding=UTF8&colid=C0XVZ38E5WD9&coliid=I1EPDGRY73N5Q2
#   old-price new-price       date-added priority rating total-ratings comment                                                             picture page
# 1       N/A           January 10, 2014             N/A                       http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51MtOOm493L._SL500_SL135_.jpg    1
# 2       N/A              July 20, 2014             N/A                       http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31GBqOHskyL._SL500_SL135_.jpg    1
```

If the set of column names varies across the json files, you can use:

```
library(dplyr)
rbind_all(lapply(readLines('mydata.json'), jsonlite::fromJSON))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm getting this error: Error in parseJSON(txt) : parse error: premature EOF. Do you know the reason for this kind of error? Cheers!

Comment: @warwick12 Maybe you're missing a closing `]` on one of the lines. You can do something like: `which(lapply(readLines('mydata.json'), function(x) tryCatch({jsonlite::fromJSON(x); 1}, error=function(e) 0)) == 0)` to see which lines throw errors, then inspect those lines in your .json file.

Comment: Superb. Thanks for your help! works perfectly fine now. Cheers!!